# Анализ изображения - имеется ли на нем человек

Tags: python, python-3.x, нейронные-сети

Как провести анализ изображения - имеется ли на нем человек?

Для проекта нужна программа, которая будет распознавать фото на аватарке и анализировать, если на фото человек.

Что можно использовать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это очень обширная задача. Лучше будет нанять специалиста по "Deep Learning" если вы никогда этим не занимались.

Если все же решите заняться этим самому то вот несколько разрозненных советов:

Скорее всего вам понадобиться большой набор тренировочных данных (изображений) для обучения. Эти данные должны быть заведомо размечены - т.е. в вашем случае достаточно будет разделить все изображения на две категории - там где присутствуют люди (`True` или `1`) и там где их нет (`False` или `0`).

Кроме того вам надо будет всеръез изучить что из себя представляют "Сверточные Нейронные Сети" (CNN - "Convolutional Neural Networks") и как ими пользоваться.

[Вот неплохая подборка рабочих примеров с использованием библиотеки Keras - смотрите секцию "Working with images"](https://github.com/fchollet/keras-resources)

В мире CNN существует много различных архитектур, которые показывают различные результаты (точность классификации / предсказаний). Вот небольшой список хорошо зарекомендовавших себя CNN архитектур:

- VGG16
- VGG19
- ResNet50
- Inception V3
- GoogLeNet
- Inception-ResNet-v2

Также не помешало бы пройти несколько курсов по "Machine Learning" и по "Deep Learning" для того, чтобы более-менее понимать как это все работает.

Удачи!